# Layout followed by webview is not visible

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to make an Activity which has a ViewPager that contains WebView and a Linearlayout, WebView will display articles and Linearlayout will have EditText and Button to submit reviews of the article. Articles may or may not contain scroll. i have tried following code, It is showing article but review part is missing

```
 <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLay1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewDoubt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:text="Review Section" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write Review Here"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: webview has `height` of `match_parent` which will cover full screen.

Comment: Use `LinearLayout` as a parent layout and use `weight` property.

Comment: changed LinearLayout with RelativeLayout, now Title Text, EditText and Submit Button are visible,But i want them to come just after webview is over. Tried android:layout_below="@+id/relativeWeb",it didn't worked again all review components gone invisible

Comment: @NayanaBhoj Need Both webview and linearlayout at half of screen? Check my answer.

Comment: yes it worked fine all contents are visible but,still my problem didn't solved as i need review layout to come just after webview,Second linear layout due to weight is fixed on screen webview content is dynamic it adds scroller where needed.

Comment: @NayanaBhoj Web view has a its own scroll functionality. It can adjust its scroll. And further for review show me screenshot how do you want it? And also reply quick so easy to solve

Comment: After click on submit what happen?? And you need to add review part as html code then just use my answer and display using it

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:id="@+id/linearLay1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewDoubt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:text="Review Section" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Write Review Here"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### EDIT:

You can add your `Webview` to `ScrollView` and when you scroll then show your `Review content` using `ScrollView` last `index`.